# Непонятный код, цикл и поля

Tags: java, циклы, простые-числа

Цикл: `for (j = 2; j < i; j++)`, в чем заключается `j<i`. Как это понять? Откуда мы придумали `j`?

```java
public class Za {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int i, j; // Объявление переменных i и j.

    boolean isprime; // Объявление переменной isprime

    for (i = 2; i < 100; i++) { // Объявление цикла
      isprime = true; //Вопрос: Зачем здесь это?


      for (j = 2; j < i; j++) /* Не ясно объявление цикла? Ведь i=2, 
         а тут опять пишем j=2 и еще пишем j<i (как это возможно если Они оба   
         равны 2). Вообще зачем, что написали внутри цикла */

        if ((i % j) == 0)
          isprime = false; // Непонятно, почему мы делим по модулю  и
                           // если без остатка вернется false

      if (isprime) // Не понятно эта управляющая конструкция
        System.out.println(i + " is prime.");
    }
  }
}

// Почему создается это: 

isprime = true;
// Проверить, делится ли число без остатка.
for (j = 2; j < i; j++)
  // Если число делится без остатка, оно простое
  if ((i % j) == 0)
    isprime = false;
```

Comment: В заголовке следует написать краткий заголовок, а вопросы уже в теле вопроса.

Comment: Вы где-то взяли код и не можете понять что он делает?

Comment: код взял в инете

Answer (score 5):

Дописал пояснения комментариями в коде:

```java
for (i = 2; i < 100; i++) { // перебираем все числа от двух до ста
  isprime = true; // если не доказано обратное - число простое


  for (j = 2; j < i; j++) //  перебираем все числа от двух до текущего числа (хотя достаточно до Sqrt(i))

    if ((i % j) == 0)
      isprime = false; // если остаток равен нулю, то текущее число i делится нацело на делитель j и простым быть не может. После этого должен стоять break, т.к. дальше искать делители бессмісленно

  if (isprime) // если не было найдено ни одного делителя, то число простое
    System.out.println(i + " is prime.");
}
```

Comment: isprime = true; // если не доказано обратное - число простое а почему мы это написаи после  for (i = 2; i < 100; i++) а не до

Comment: Потому, что нам нужно проверить на простоту **каждое** из чисел 2 - 100

Comment: мне нужен наставник обиван на бесплатной основе срочно(

Answer (score 2):

Это алгоритм поиска простых чисел до 100, второй цикл это все числа меньше i-го для проверки(поэтому и j < i), а isprime - это обычный флаг, который в итоге проверяется для отображения числа в консоль.

Answer (score 1):

> //  и это не ясно почему мы так сделали? ведь i=2 а тут опять пишем j=2

У вас `i=2` только в первой итерации цикла по i, во всех последующих нет.

> // и это не ясно, почему мы делим по модулю  и говорим если  без остатка то ошибка ( false)

Опять неверно, если делится без остатка то присваиваем булевой переменной значение `false`, а не ошибка.
А вообще:

> Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. Если у вас возник вопрос по домашнему заданию, не просите его сделать за вас. Задайте конкретный вопрос о проблеме, которую вы не можете решить. Программирование — это то, в чём надо разбираться самому, либо не заниматься им вовсе. Если для вас программирование — лишний предмет в учебной программе, есть сайты и люди на этих сайтах, выполняющие задания за материальное вознаграждение. Здесь предлагать выполнить работу за вас и наоборот — моветон.

Answer (score 0):

Смысл в том, что это циклы, и ты говоришь, что выполняй внутренний цикл пока j < i, как только это неравенство перестанет выполняться то выйди из цикла. Это имеет смысл так как следующий раз i будет равно 3 4 5 и т.д. до 10